# A string is required here Error in formula expert

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am using crystal reports Xi. I have Dataset1(ado.net) in C#. In my crystal report in detail section b. I want to saw data of expiry date if dt_expiry_date not equal to 9998-12-31 or 9999-12-31 otherwise detail section b suppress. Whenever I go to section b and suppress format formula editor and enter following code.

```
if{DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} = "9999-12-31" OR {DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} = "9998-12-31" OR {DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} = "31-12-9999" OR {DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} = "31-12-9998" OR {DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} = Date(9999/12/31) OR {DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} = Date (9998/12/31)
Then
    True 
else
    False
```

A string is required here error comes. and my section does not be suppressed during run time of my crystal report. and showing data of 31/12/9998 or 31/12999. so please help. 
Thanks in Advance.[Formula Workshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bakY.jpg)

Comment: Hello everyone,

Comment: Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like {DataTable2.dt_expiry_date} is a string and hence you should not be comparing it to a date (as in the last two expressions).

But a basic troubleshooting step is to isolate the specific offending expression. Crystal typically highlights the position where the problem is located. Or you can remove parts of the code until you isolate what expression is causing the problem.